# How to make VLC Player and GOM Player respond to the Remote Control?

Tags: vlc-media-player, remote-control, gom-player

The remote control included with some desktop or notebook works quite ok with Windows Media Player, but is there a very trustworthy way of making the remote control work with VLC Player and the GOM Player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

software to intercept the remotes messages.
then relay them to your media player.
The software will take care of what messages are sent.
eg.. you push B.1 on the remote. The pc gets the message. the software then converts the message into eg.. spacebar(press)
You decide what button presses do what. you define them in the software.
Look around for it.

## You can use a Wii remote as a pc mouse/remote controll.  software and a bluetooth adapter is all you need.